# solve the equation of calculus

Tags: calculus, integration

Hi there actually i'm stuck on a question on the calculus and if you help with it this will be great...

If the $Q$ is a charge passes in a circuit, $Q= \int_{t_1}^{t_2}i(t)\ dt$, where $i(t)$ is the current.

Find the charge for $t_1= 0.25$,$t_2= 0.8$ if the current given by $i(t) = 5e^{-2t}+ 3.4$.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You need to learn the basics of formatting math for this site. See http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: I have made a few basic edits. Please check that it is correct. I suggest deleting the image, it does not add anything.

Comment: @almagest ...apart from the calculator's brand :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $\int 5\cdot e^{-2\cdot t}+3.5 \,dt$

We can separate the summands. And $5$ can be factored out.

$5\cdot\int  e^{-2\cdot t} \, dt + \int 3.5 \,dt$

In general it is $\int e^{ct} \, dt=\frac{1}{c}\cdot e^{ct}$. $c$ is a constant. In your case $c=-2$

=$5\cdot (-\frac{1}{2}\cdot e^{-2t})+3.5t$

Plugging in the lower and upper bound

$5\cdot (-\frac{1}{2}\cdot e^{-2\cdot 0.8})+3.5\cdot 0.8-5\cdot (-\frac{1}{2}\cdot e^{-2\cdot 0.25})-3.5\cdot 0.25=2.93659$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. One has

> $$
> \int_a^b e^{\large -ct}dt=\frac{e^{\large -ac}-e^{\large -bc}}{c},\quad c\neq0.
> $$